# Is sexual reproduction outside the same biological family possible? Has it ever occured successfully?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, taxonomy, hybridization

Are there any examples of two species taxonomically classified in **different [biological families](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_%28biology%29)** that have successfully hybridized and produced viable offspring? If not, is there an example of where reproduction occured with non-viable offspring?

To be clear, I mean regular sexual reproduction that could occur in the natural world outside a lab. Even so, I'd be curious to know if it could even occur in a lab without direct genetic manipulation.

For example, grolar bears which are [ursid hybrids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursid_hybrid) between different species in the *Ursus* genus are known to exist. Also ursid hybrids between bear species in different genuses have been produced in captivity (sloth bear *Melursus ursinus* x Malayan sun bear *Ursus malayanus* and sloth bear x Asiatic black bear *Ursus thibetanus*). Would an extra-familial hybridisation be possible? Would this be more likely in the plant kingdom?

This question is inspired by a [separate question on the Gardening SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2491/can-i-cross-pollinate-basil-and-chili-peppers) which hints at a general lack of understanding of the genetic similarity required for cross-pollination in plants. It made me wonder whether there are any exceptions to the general assumption that extra-familial hybridisation is impossible.

Comment: Following the definitions of [hybrid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_(biology)) and of [sexual reproduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_reproduction), one could consider [Horizontal Gene Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_gene_transfer) and answer YES to your question with the case of the [photosynthetic sea slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysia_chlorotica) for example.

Comment: I should have been more specific to limit this to gene transfer/recombination occurring by sexual reproduction (i.e. vertical gene transfer) but thanks for the point.

Comment: One of the problems is that "Family" and really any taxonomic designation are fuzzy. We often don't even _really_ know where to draw the line between two species, even in animals, where such things are relatively easy. Since none of the taxonomic designations tell us anything about genetic distance except "the two taxa are genetically different from each other", any examples of inter-familial hybridization won't tell you anything about the general likelihood of such an occurrence...

Comment: A more valuable question might be "What is the maximum genetic distance at which hybridization by sexual reproduction has been observed?" And of course, the answer to that is, "I don't know" :P. Which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi As stated, there is a practical purpose behind the question, not merely a completely idle wondering. A new gardener without much backgrounding in biology wants to avoid hybridisation in her vegetable patch. How do you give simple instructions on avoiding it? For the lay-person the problems of taxonomic fuzziness are of zero interest. She just has labels with the species written on. Based on the single answer, I'd tell her first only be concerned about inter-genus and inter-species hybrids and then on how to prevent such cross pollination.

Comment: Yes, and as I said, single examples don't allow you to draw any conclusions about the general case. Will species x hybridise with species y is the appropriate question to ask in this case.

Comment: @Lisa My point is that even when you say hybrid via sexual reproduction you do not exclude Horizontal gene transfer. There are so many different way of reproducing sexually that our definitions are usually quite broad. But your question is interesting, I just thought it was worth stating horizontal gene transfer as this process fits in the definitions of sexual reproduction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Interfamilial hybrids have never, to my knowledge, been recorded occurring naturally (without human intervention).

In plants, somatic inter-familial hybrids have been produced for a wide variety of species pairs in the lab (e.g. between carrot and barley; Kisaka et al. 1997).

In animals, there are some historical reports of hybrids between chickens (Mathis & MacDougald 1987) or peafowl (Serebrovsky 1929), both in Phasianidae, and guineafowl (in Numididae). The animal example meets your condition of being outside the lab, although they were produced by breeders.

**Refs**

- [Kisaka, H., Kisaka, M., Kanno, A. & Kameya, T. (1997) Production and analysis of plants that are somatic hybrids of barley (Hordeum vulgare L.) and carrot (Daucus carota L.). TAG Theoretical and Applied Genetics. 94 (2), 221–226.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s001220050403)
- [Mathis, G.F. & McDougald, L.R. (1987) Evaluation of interspecific hybrids of the chicken, guinea fowl, and Japanese quail for innate resistance to coccidia. Avian Diseases. 31 (4), 740–745.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3442527)
- [Serebrovsky, A. (1929) Observations on interspecific hybrids of the fowl. Journal of Genetics. 21 (3), 327–340.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02984211)